# Java program that does simple string manipulation is not working correctly

Tags: java

I wrote this program for school and it almost works, but there is one problem.  The goal of the program is to take an inputted string and create a new string out of each word in the input beginning with a vowel.

Example:

input: `It is a hot and humid day.`
output: `Itisaand.`

Here is the driver:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String input = console.nextLine();
    Class strings = new Class(input);
    int beg=0;
    for(int j=0;j<input.length();j++)
    {
        if(strings.isVowel(j)&&(j==0||input.charAt(j-1)==' '))
            beg=j;
        else if(strings.endWord(j)&&(beg==0||input.charAt(beg-1)==' '))
        {
            strings.findWord(beg, j);       
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Output: ");
    strings.printAnswer();
}

}
```

And here is the class:

```
public class Class {

    String input="",answer="";
    public Class(String input1)
    {
        input = input1;
    }


    public boolean isVowel(int loc)
    {
        return (input.charAt(loc)=='U'||input.charAt(loc)=='O'||input.charAt(loc)=='I'||input.charAt(loc)=='E'||input.charAt(loc)=='A'||input.charAt(loc)=='a'||input.charAt(loc)=='e'||input.charAt(loc)=='i'||input.charAt(loc)=='o'||input.charAt(loc)=='u');
    }
    public boolean endWord(int loc)
    {
        return (input.charAt(loc)==' '||input.charAt(loc)=='.'||input.charAt(loc)=='?'||input.charAt(loc)=='!');
    }
    public void findWord(int beg,int end)
    {
        answer = answer+(input.substring(beg,end));
    }
    public void printAnswer()
    {
        System.out.println(answer+".");
    }
}
```

With this code, i get the output:
`Itisaa hotandand humidand humid summerand humid summer day.`

By removing this piece of code:

```
&& (j == 0 || input.charAt(j-1) == ' ')
```

I get the proper output, but it doesn't work if an inputted word has more than one vowel in it.

For example:

input: `Apples and bananas.`
output: `and.`

Can someone please explain:
a) why the code is printing out words beginning with consonants as it is and
b) how I could fix it.

Also, the methods in the class I've written can't be changed.

Comment: Please don't name a class `Class`...

Comment: I know I've been told that before but I started this program a while ago and I just never changed it.

Comment: It would take 3 seconds to change it now...

Comment: Yes, it's a very quick fix, especially if you're using Netbeans or the like, Find and Replace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code was:
It was counting the same word multiple times, due to it finding vowels and starting the word search process over again.

Heres how I went about solving the problem, while still keeping your code looking relatively the same:  All I changed was your loop

```
for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        if(strings.isVowel(i) &&(i==0 || strings.endWord(i-1))){ 
            beg = i;
            for(int j = i; j < input.length();j++) //look for end of word
            {
                if(strings.endWord(j)) //word has ended
                {
                    i = j; //start from end of last word
                    strings.findWord(beg, j);         
                    break; //word done, end word search
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As mentioned above, there are better ways to go about this, and there are some pretty glaring flaws in the setup, but you wanted an answer, so here you go

Answer (score 4):

Here's a better algorithm:

1. split the input into an array of words
2. iterate over each word
3. if the word begins with a vowel, append it to the output

The easiest way to split the input would be to use [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = console.nextLine();
    String[] words = input.split(" ");
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (String s : words) {
        if (startsWithVowel(s)) {
            output.append(s);
        }
        else {
            output.append(getPunc(s));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(output.toString());
}

public static boolean startsWithVowel(String s) {
     char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
     char firstChar = s.toLowerCase().charAt(0);
     for (char v : vowels) {
         if (v == firstChar) {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }

public static String getPunc(String s) {
    if (s.matches(".*[.,:;!?]$")) {
        int len = s.length();
        return s.substring(len - 1, len);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: This does not keep the punctuation marks... So it is not exactly what he wanted input: `It is a hot and humid day.` output: `Itisaand.` <-- see the dot

Comment: @noone - FIXED.  Thanks, I didn't see that.

Comment: Yep, but now it's not really much different from my version. +1 ;)

Comment: @noone - Then I'll upvote your answer and remove my way over-critical comments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally i would suggest you where to fix your code, but it's seems there is a lot of bad code practice in here.

- Mass Concatenation should be apply be StringBuilder.
- **Never** call a class `Class`
- Conditions are too long and can be shorten by a static string of Vowels and apply .contains(Your-Char)
- Spaces, Indentations required for readability purposes.
- A different way of attacking this problem, may probably accelerate your efficiency.

**Another approch** will be `Split` the code by spaces and loop through the resulted array for starting vowels letters and then Append them to the result string.

Answer (score 1):

I think best approach is to split input and then check each word if it starts with vowel.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Input: ");
  String str = console.next();

  String[] input = str.split(" ");

  StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

  String test;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
  {
      test = input[i];

      if (test.charAt(0) == 'U' || test.charAt(0) == 'O'
          || test.charAt(0) == 'I' || test.charAt(0) == 'E'
          || test.charAt(0) == 'A' || test.charAt(0) == 'a'
          || test.charAt(0) == 'e' || test.charAt(0) == 'i'
          || test.charAt(0) == 'o' || test.charAt(0) == 'u')
     {
           s.append(input[i]);

     }

   }
   System.out.println(s);

}
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot more readable if you stored the first character in a variable rather than repeating `input[i].charAt(0)` ten times!  I also don't see why you would append an empty string... that makes no sense.

Comment: modified as per comments :) Thanks

Comment: How about `char c = input[i].toLowerCase().charAt(0);` ?

Comment: that's great too. there's a lot to learn for me also. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

A better readable and more maintainable version doing what you want:

```
public static String buildWeirdSentence(String input) {
    Pattern vowels = Pattern.compile("A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u");
    Pattern signs = Pattern.compile("!|\\.|,|:|;|\\?");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : input.split(" ")) {
        String firstCharacter = word.substring(0, 1);
        Matcher vowelMatcher = vowels.matcher(firstCharacter);
        if (vowelMatcher.matches()) {
            builder.append(word);
        } else {
            // we still might want the last character because it might be a sign
            int wordLength = word.length();
            String lastCharacter = word.substring(wordLength - 1, wordLength);
            Matcher signMatcher = signs.matcher(lastCharacter);
            if (signMatcher.matches()) {
                builder.append(lastCharacter);
            }
        }
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

In use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildWeirdSentence("It is a hot and humid day.")); // Itisaand.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you override the first `beg` when a word has more that vowel. for example with `Apples` beg goes to `0` and before you could call `findWord` to catch it, it gets overridden with `4` which is the index of `e`. And this is what screws up your algorithm.

You need to note that you have already found a vowel until you have called `finWord`, for that you can add a boolean variable `haveFirstVowel` and set it the first time you have found one to true and only enter the branch for setting that variable to true if you haven't already set it. After you have called `findWord` set it back to false.

Next you need to detect the start of a word, otherwise for example the `o` of `hot` could wrongly signal a first vowel.

```
Class strings = new Class(input);
int beg = 0;
boolean haveFirstVowel = false;
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
    boolean startOfWord = (beg == 0 || input.charAt(j - 1) == ' ');
    if (startOfWord && ! haveFirstVowel && strings.isVowel(j)) {
        beg = j;
        haveFirstVowel = true;
    }
    else if (strings.endWord(j) && haveFirstVowel) {
        strings.findWord(beg, j);
        haveFirstVowel = false;
    }
}
System.out.print("Output: ");
strings.printAnswer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think overall the algorithm is not bad. It's just that the implementation can definitely be better.

Regarding to the problem, you only need to call **findWord**() when:

1. You have found a vowel, and
2. You have reached the end of a word.

Your code forgot the rule (1), therefore the main() can be modified as followed:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Input: ");
String input = console.nextLine();
Class strings = new Class(input);
int beg = 0;
boolean foundVowel = false; // added a flag indicating whether a vowel has been found or not
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
    if (strings.isVowel(j) && (j == 0 || input.charAt(j - 1) == ' ')) {
        beg = j;
        foundVowel = true;
    } else if (strings.endWord(j) && (beg == 0 || input.charAt(beg - 1) == ' ')) {
        if (foundVowel) { // only call findWord() when you have found a vowel and reached the end of a word
            strings.findWord(beg, j);
            foundVowel = false; // remember to reset the flag
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("Output: ");
strings.printAnswer();
```